# SQL - Error when inserting into table from union all

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a new table from one table using different values. But for some reason I am getting a

```
       'Operand type clash: date is incompatible with float' error on line 1

        insert into mvp(Acco, Bal, BalDate)
        Select Acco, 
           l_Date,
           sum(amount) over (partition by Acco order by l_Date asc) as  amount
        from (
            Select Acco, l_Date, sum(amount) amount
            from (
                Select  Acco, cbs as amount
                , '2020-06-21' as l_Date
                from homeworktable

                union all

                Select  Acco, abs as amount
                , '2020-06-21' as l_Date
               from homeworktable

               ) a
         group by Acco, l_Date
       ) a
```

I don't understand why there would be a problem on line 1. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

you have inverted the columns in the insert:

```
l_Date ==> Bal
amount ==> BalDate
```

the insert should be: insert into mvp(Acco, BalDate, Bal)....